# Is there a better way to write REGEXP in sql to select unique transaction number R-0001 and R-AD-0001

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like, regexp-like

Am having  a lot of transaction number store in my db, `example I-0001, IN-0001, N-0001, S-0001, SN-0001, R-0001 , R-AD-0001, and R-AA-00001.`
Every time a new row insert, I will select the maximum number of transaction numbers and + 1 to keep track of every transaction number.
Here is my initial SQL `` SELECT MAX(`transaction_invoice`) FROM sw_invoice WHERE `transaction_invoice` LIKE '%N-%' ``, but I found out using `LIKE` to select for example maximum number of N-, `LIKE` SQL will also select N-0001 and SN-0001 together
[Example of LIKE SQL result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JiKL.png)
To solve this I found out REGEXP might solve my issue here is example SQL
`` SELECT * FROM `sw_invoice` WHERE `transaction_invoice` REGEXP '^N-' ``, this SQL works well when select maximum number of N-, but when its come to select R-0001, it will also select R-AD-0001, and R-AA-00001 which start with R-
[Example of REGEXP SQL result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxZab.png)

Is there a way any SQL can only select the maximum transaction number I require? for example if I select transaction number start with R-, its only return the maximum number of R- not R-AD-

Comment: Why not store the **numbers** as **numbers** and use an auto increment?

Comment: total having around 30+ difference format of transaction number didn't plan to separate them into difference column or table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the leading wildcard from the `like`:

```
SELECT MAX(`transaction_invoice`)
FROM sw_invoice
WHERE `transaction_invoice` LIKE 'N-%';
```

You don't need regular expressions for this.

If you need to handle hyphens in the first part, then you need regular expressions:

```
where transaction_invoice regexp '^N-[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: But when it come to select R-, this SQL will also select R-AD- and R-AA together

Comment: ```where transaction_invoice regexp '^N-[0-9]+$'``` this sql solve my question